# Removing lines of file depending on information in previous and next lines with java

Tags: java

I have data that looks like this.

```
CONTIG  POSITION    INFO
CF1_seqReads_contig_5   117537  .   C   T   222 .   DP=31;VDB=0.0507;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,16,11;MQ=38;FQ=-108    GT:PL:GQ    1/1:255,81,0:99
CF1_seqReads_contig_5   117541  .   A   T   222 .   DP=30;VDB=0.0381;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,16,11;MQ=39;FQ=-108    GT:PL:GQ    1/1:255,81,0:99
CF1_seqReads_contig_9   96299   .   G   T   150 .   DP=44;VDB=0.0330;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,5,20;MQ=31;FQ=-102 GT:PL:GQ    1/1:183,75,0:99
CF1_seqReads_contig_9   96305   .   G   C   88  .   DP=43;VDB=0.0279;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,4,5;MQ=29;FQ=-54   GT:PL:GQ    1/1:121,27,0:51
CF1_seqReads_contig_11  73382   .   G   C   37.2    .   DP=19;VDB=0.0063;AF1=0.5263;AC1=1;DP4=0,1,2,3;MQ=47;FQ=-17.1;PV4=1,0.14,1,0.0015    GT:PL:GQ    0/1:67,0,10:13
CF1_seqReads_contig_11  130161  .   G   T   59.3    .   DP=30;VDB=0.0545;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,2,3;MQ=55;FQ=-42   GT:PL:GQ    1/1:92,15,0:27
CF1_seqReads_contig_16  8578    .   G   A   167 .   DP=34;VDB=0.0187;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,3,19;MQ=29;FQ=-93  GT:PL:GQ    1/1:200,66,0:99
CF1_seqReads_contig_19  169 .   C   T   110 .   DP=37;VDB=0.0545;AF1=0.5336;AC1=1;DP4=0,3,1,9;MQ=36;FQ=-18.1;PV4=1,0.33,1,0.014 GT:PL:GQ    0/1:140,0,9:12
CF1_seqReads_contig_19  190 .   G   T   30.1    .   DP=39;VDB=0.0004;AF1=0.5102;AC1=1;DP4=0,3,6,0;MQ=47;FQ=-13.2;PV4=0.012,1,1,1    GT:PL:GQ    0/1:60,0,14:17
CF1_seqReads_contig_20  229322  .   C   T   222 .   DP=55;VDB=0.0521;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,19,27;MQ=57;FQ=-165    GT:PL:GQ    1/1:255,138,0:99
CF1_seqReads_contig_40  184 .   C   A   36.5    .   DP=23;VDB=0.0014;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=1,0,11,0;MQ=29;FQ=-34;PV4=1,0.0039,1,0.29  GT:PL:GQ    1/1:68,7,0:12
CF1_seqReads_contig_40  194 .   C   T   59  .   DP=28;VDB=0.0014;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,1,17,0;MQ=29;FQ=-62;PV4=0.056,0.44,1,0.3 GT:PL:GQ    1/1:92,35,0:67
CF1_seqReads_contig_40  197 .   C   G   59  .   DP=29;VDB=0.0063;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,11,0;MQ=29;FQ=-60  GT:PL:GQ    1/1:92,33,0:63
CF1_seqReads_contig_49  111973  .   G   A   32.3    .   DP=13;VDB=0.0063;AF1=0.543;AC1=1;DP4=0,1,3,1;MQ=29;FQ=-19;PV4=0.4,0.44,1,0.16   GT:PL:GQ    0/1:62,0,8:11
CF1_seqReads_contig_49  124688  .   G   T   42.1    .   DP=48;VDB=0.0532;AF1=0.5064;AC1=1;DP4=2,0,4,3;MQ=45;FQ=-11.3;PV4=0.5,0.095,1,0.099  GT:PL:GQ    0/1:72,0,16:19
CF1_seqReads_contig_51  3725    .   C   T   39.3    .   DP=24;VDB=0.0381;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,1,4;MQ=29;FQ=-42   GT:PL:GQ    1/1:72,15,0:27
CF1_seqReads_contig_79  24357   .   C   T   80.1    .   DP=36;VDB=0.0435;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,4,3;MQ=34;FQ=-48   GT:PL:GQ    1/1:113,21,0:39
CF1_seqReads_contig_79  24367   .   C   T   65  .   DP=40;VDB=0.0187;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,7,1;MQ=38;FQ=-51   GT:PL:GQ    1/1:98,24,0:45
CF1_seqReads_contig_115 14710   .   C   A   80  .   DP=40;VDB=0.0381;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,1,7;MQ=60;FQ=-51   GT:PL:GQ    1/1:113,24,0:45
CF1_seqReads_contig_167 4920    .   G   T   60  .   DP=19;VDB=0.0085;AF1=0.5008;AC1=1;DP4=1,2,4,2;MQ=41;FQ=-4.12;PV4=0.52,1,0.077,0.23  GT:PL:GQ    0/1:90,0,25:28
```

I am trying to remove lines that belong to the same CONTIG and whose POSITION is less than 30 from other lines in the same CONTIG. For example the first two line would be removed because both share the same contig and their positions (117537 and 117541) differ by less than 15. The same goes for the third and fourth line. On the other hand the fifth and sixth lines would be printed because even though they share the same CONTIG their POSITIONs differ by more than 15 (130161-73382>15). I have attempted to solve this

```
public void getFilteredData(File in){
   String contig = "";
   int position = -1;
   String lastContig = "";
   int lastPosition = -1;
   String nextContig = "";
   int nextPosition = -1;

   while(in.hasNextLine()){
      String curLine = in.nextLine();
      String[] curInfo = curLine.split("\t");

      /*Isolate the snp position*/ 
      contig = curInfo[0];
      position = Integer.parseInt(curInfo[1]);
      if(file.hasNextLine()){
         String nextLine = file.nextLine();
         nextContig = nextLine.split("\t")[0];
         nextPosition = Integer.parseInt(nextLine.split("\t")[1]);
         if(nextContig.equals(contig)){
            if( nextPosition-position<15){
               System.out.println(curLine);
            }
         }
         lastContig = contig;
         lastPosition = position;
      }
   }
}
```

This code has not given me the results I was looking for. Could you please help me disentangle this problem? I thought assigning values to previous and next pieces of info would be helpful but I am at a loss. thanks

Comment: What is `file` in `file.hasNextLine()`?

Comment: that would be the file containing the data I posted.

Comment: Is the sequence of contig always maintained?

Comment: yes it is always maintained

Answer (score 0):

Just the working code, may be optimized further.

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:/contig.txt"));
    String currLine;
    String[] array;
    String contig;
    int position;

    String nextLine;
    String[] nextArray;
    String nextContig;
    int nextPosition;

    reader.readLine(); // ignore first line
    while ((currLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        array = currLine.split("\\s+");
        contig = array[0];
        position = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);

        nextLine = reader.readLine();
        if (nextLine != null) {
            nextArray = nextLine.split("\\s+");
            nextContig = nextArray[0];
            nextPosition = Integer.parseInt(nextArray[1]);

            if (nextContig.equals(contig)) {
                if (nextPosition - position < 15) {
                    System.out.println(currLine);
                }
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: Besides the code optimization, I dont see anything that changes the code to answer the question. Am I confused?